# Convert quoted string list to specific format

Tags: bash, jq

I'm using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to read some data from a JSON file.

```
after=`cat somefile.json | jq '.after[]'`
```

returns something like this:

```
"some value" "another value" "something else"
```

Basically a list of quoted strings. I now need to convert these strings into one string formatted like

```
"some value; another value; something else;"
```

I've tried a lot of combinations of for loops to try and get this working and nothing quite works.

Anyone know how this can be done? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all! I actually decided to dig deeper into the jq docs to see if I could simply leverage it to do what I want.

```
after=`cat somefile.json | jq -c -r '.after[] + "; "'` | tr -d '\n'
```

This ended up working very well. Thanks for the sed version though! Always good to see another working solution.

Answer (score 2):

use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/" /; /g; s/ "/ /g; s/"$/;"/' <<< '"some value" "another value" "something else"'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"some value; another value; something else;"
```

use sed `s` command for replacing the desire value

Comment: Slighly simpler version: `sed -e 's/" "/; /g; s/"$/;&/'`

Comment: @janos Now is much better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.after[]` returns the list of strings you describe, you can do this entirely with jq using **join** to format them as follows:

```
[ .after[] ] | join("; ") + ";"
```